# jQuery with HTML CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a problem with jQuery. How to animate new row add, new row add is already done by clicking submit. Also how to add new class and delete it. This has to be with animation. Speed of animation needs to be 1000 milliseconds. I must not change HTML or CSS (I'm a student and this is for school).

jQuery code:

```
  $("form").submit(function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var id = $("table tr").length;
    var naziv = $("#naziv").val();
    var cena = $("#cena").val();
    var kolicina = $("#kolicina").val();
    var cenaSkupaj = cena * kolicina;
    var tip = $("#tip").val();
    var rok = $("#rok_trajanja").is(":checked") ? "Potekel" : "Ni potekel";

    $("table").append("<tr><td>" + id + "</td><td>" + naziv + "</td><td>" + cena + " €</td><td>" + 
    kolicina + "</td><td>" + cenaSkupaj + " €</td><td>" + tip + "</td><td>" + rok + "</td></tr>");

  });

});
```

Comment: It seems you forgot to include a question in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like..

```
var to_add = "<tr><td>" + id + "</td><td>" + naziv + "</td><td>" + cena + " €</td><td>" + 
    kolicina + "</td><td>" + cenaSkupaj + " €</td><td>" + tip + "</td><td>" + rok + "</td></tr>";

$(to_add).appendTo("table").show(1000);
```